# Select all threads between users with newest message

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problems with selecting all threads (inbox message system) between two users.

The database structure is similar to below:

```
+----+---------------+----------------+---------+----------+
| id | id_first_user | id_second_user | message | datetime |
+----+---------------+----------------+---------+----------+
```

Let's say we have user id 1 and user id 2 and let's look at the scenario below:

user_id (1) sent message to user id (2), now the data is inserted and we have it like below:

```
+----+---------------+----------------+--------------+----------+
| id | id_first_user | id_second_user |   message    | datetime |
+----+---------------+----------------+--------------+----------+
|  1 |             1 |              2 | some message | 11:11:10 |
+----+---------------+----------------+--------------+----------+
```

However, if user id 2 reply to the user id 1 we will have something like below

```
+----+---------------+----------------+--------------+----------+
| id | id_first_user | id_second_user |   message    | datetime |
+----+---------------+----------------+--------------+----------+
|  1 |             1 |              2 | some message | 11:11:10 |
|  2 |             2 |              1 | some reply   | 11:12:15 |
+----+---------------+----------------+--------------+----------+
```

So in general - this is one thread between these two users and we are only interested in the newest message and in that case it will be "some reply" of date 2020-02-10 11:12:15. It's important to mention that there would not be only two users in the application so it should work between all users ids.

So far i've created distinct query with group by but it doesnt work as i expect:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_first_user, id_second_user 
FROM tablename 
WHERE 
    (id_first_user= :logged_user_id) OR 
    (id_second_user = :logged_user_id) 
GROUP BY id_first_user 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

In the result of above query i receive duplicated rows where only id_first_user and id_second_user are allocated different, like below:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id_first_user] => 1
        [id_second_user] => 2
        [message] => some reply
        [datetime] => 2020-02-10 11:12:15
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id_first_user] => 2
        [id_second_user] => 1
        [message] => some reply
        [datetime] => 2020-02-10 11:12:15
    )
```

How can i fix that? What should I do?

Edit - I've tried to use an aggregate function and now my query looks like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_first_user, id_second_user, max(datetime) 
     FROM tablename 
     WHERE 
          (id_first_user= :logged_user_id) OR 
          (id_second_user = :logged_user_id) 
     GROUP BY id_first_user 
     ORDER BY max(datetime) DESC, id_first_user
```

And now the difference is in the date but there is still a duplicate

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id_first_user] => 1
        [id_second_user] => 2
        [message] => some reply
        [datetime] => 2020-02-10 11:12:15
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id_first_user] => 2
        [id_second_user] => 1
        [message] => some reply
        [datetime] => 2020-02-10 11:11:10
    )
```

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry i've tried tlo use aggregating function max on datetime and now there is a difference in the datetime but still there is a duplicate.

Comment: @Marcin what MySQL version used? It may be critical for solution

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev libmysql - 5.5.47

Answer (score 1):

> we are only interested in the newest message and in that case it will be "some reply" of date 2020-02-10 11:12:15.

```
SELECT *
FROM dialogs
WHERE (LEAST(id_first_user, id_second_user), GREATEST(id_first_user, id_second_user)) 
     =(LEAST(@user1, @user2), GREATEST(@user1, @user2))
ORDER BY `datetime` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the most recent message for a given user and each *other* user id.  Here is one method:

```
select d.*
from dialogs d
where :logged_user_id in (d.id_first_user, d.id_second_user) and
      d.datetime = (select max(d2.datetime)
                    from dialogs d2
                    where (d2.id_first_user, d2.id_second_user) in
                          ( (d1.id_first_user, d1.id_second_user),
                            (d1.id_second_user, d1.id_first_user)
                          )
                   );
```